# golang datadog tracing include trace information in outgoing requests

Tags: go, trace, datadog

I'm using golang and datadog for tracing and my simplified setup is as follows

`client -> service 1 -> service 2`

in `service 1` I'm using `gopkg.in/DataDog/dd-trace-go.v1/contrib/gorilla/mux` so that the trace and span information are logged properly which originate from the client.  Now when I call `service 2` from `service 1` I want to include this same information in the request going out so that the trace information is stitched correctly.  However I don't think the `gopkg.in/DataDog/dd-trace-go.v1/contrib/gorilla/mux` package does this automatically, is this assumption correct ? if so then I need to write some middleware to the router which extracts this information and stores it to be used later in any outgoing request.  Is this the correct approach to this or is there a simpler method to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll need some code somewhere to propagate the trace context between the services to create a distributed trace. Assuming both services are in Go, [the docs have a short example](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/trace_collection/custom_instrumentation/go/#distributed-tracing) of the client and server. Make sure you read about the different propagation options on the docs as well, there are a few different standards.